# Sum values in one column based on specific values in other column

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have a DataFrame in Pandas for example:

`df = pd.DataFrame("a":[0,0,1,1,0], "penalty":["12", "15","13","100", "22"])`

and how can I sum values in column "penalty" but I would like to sum only these values from column "penalty" which have values 0 in column "a" ?

Comment: you can make a lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your dataframe with this:

```
import pandas as pd
data ={'a':[0,0,1,1,0],'penalty':[12, 15,13,100, 22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.loc[df['a'].eq(0), 'penalty'].sum())
```

This way you are selecting the column `penalty` from your dataframe where the column `a` is equal to 0. Afterwards, you are performing the `.sum()` operation, hence returning your expected output (49). The only change I made was remove the quotation mark so that the values for the column `penalty` were interpreted as integers and not strings. If the input are necessarily strings, you can simply change this with `df['penalty'] = df['penalty'].astype(int)`

Comment: You should avoid the chained indexing here.  Use `df.loc[df['a'].eq(0), 'penalty']`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will edit my answer to fit this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the rows which has 0 in column a and calculate the sum of penalty column.

```
import pandas as pd
data ={'a':[0,0,1,1,0],'penalty':[12, 15,13,100, 22]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[df.a == 0].penalty.sum()
```